# Where are Eudora data files?

Tags: wine, files, location

I installed Eudora 7 under Wine. It worked fine. But now I would like to replace the data files - mailboxes, filters, stationery, attachments - with the files in my windows installation.

But I can't find them.  When I look at the location of an attachment it shows: 
home .wine dosdevices c ...

But nowhere can I find a ".wine" directory!  Is it hidden?

How can I find this directory?

Answer (score 1):

Yes `.wine` is a hidden folder under user's home directory. To see the hidden files in your home directory:

- Open your home dierctory in Nautilus file browser.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to see the hidden files and folders. Afterwards press the same key combination to hide the contents again.

From a terminal you can see files under wine as,

```
$ cd && cd .wine
```

The first part of the command above changes directory to your home folder, and if the first command is successful then it takes you to the `.wine` folder under your home.

Or your desired location as

```
$ cd && cd .wine/dosdevices/c
```

Comment: Is your problem resolved?